# Tricky Rails migration and modeling involving a self-join ":users" table and a ":bands" table: simultaneous one-to-many and many-to-many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, one-to-many, rails-migrations, self-join

My `:users` table is successfully self-joined with all the necessary confusing (to this newbie) code and tables necessary to do that.  `:users`'s two groups are `:teachers` and `:students`.

I need to make the group `:teachers` join one-to-many with the `:bands` table (a band may have only one teacher) while at the same time joining `:students` many-to-many with the `:bands` table (a band may have many students and vice versa).

What's tripping me up is `:students` and `:teachers` are both `:users`.  Therefore, if for a moment I pretend that there's only one kind of user and go for a one-to-many (teacher) relationship, then the `Band` model `belongs_to :user` and the `User` model `has_many :bands`

But if I go for the many-to-many (student) relationship instead, the `Band` model `has_many :users, through :user_bands` join table and the `User` model `has_many :bands, through :user_bands` join table. (`UserBands` model has `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :band` in this case)

But I need both relationships at the same time.  I haven't actually tried putting `has_many :bands` in the `User` model while simultaneously having `has_many :users` (through join table) and `belongs_to :users` in the Bands model because, unless Rails is more magic than I give it credit for, it won't differentiate that teachers get the single-to-many while the students get the many-to-many.

I have not attempted my best guess (below) because I'm admittedly skittish: my database already has a sprawling number of many-to-many relations that are intact and functioning properly.  The one time I attempted to make a complicated alteration to it earlier in the process, it thoroughly messed things up so badly that rolling back and undoing model alterations didn't get me back to where I'd started somehow, so I had to go back to rebuilding everything from scratch after pulling out enough hair for a tonsure.  I do have github this time, so I *should* be able to revert the project if it blows up like before, but git is its own fussy minefield.

So if some folks could take a look at my guess first, I'd deeply appreciate it.  Does it look right?  Do I need to make changes before updating the database schema?:

1. In `User` model, add `has_many :bands`.
2. In `Band` model, add `has_many :students, through :user_bands` ; add `belongs_to :teacher`
3. In the `create_bands` migration, add `t.belongs_to :teacher`
4. In `UserBands` model, add `belongs_to :teacher` and add `t.belongs_to :teacher` in the `create_user_bands` migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The needed associations are not self-joining. Self-joins are primarily used to build tree like hierarchies from a single table - see [the guides for a good example](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins).

You just need  multiple associations between two tables - the key thing here to remember is that you must use unique names for each association. If you declare multiple associations with the same name the later just overwrites the former without error.

## Teachers

```
class AddTeacherIdToBands < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :bands, :teacher, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bands_as_teacher, 
    class_name: 'Band',
    foreign_key: 'teacher_id'
end

class Band < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher, 
    class_name: 'User'
end
```

We name the association `bands_as_teacher` to avoid conflict and confusion. This requires us to explicitly set the `class_name` and `foreign_key` options as they cannot be deduced from the name.

This is kind of where you tripped up and overcomplicated your solution. If the association is one to many you don't need to involve a join table.

## Students

To create the association between a band and its members you need a m2m association through a join table:

```
class CreateBandMemberships < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :band_memberships do |t|
      t.references :band, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Band < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :band_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :band_memberships
end

class BandMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :band
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :band_memberships
  has_many :bands, through: :band_memberships
end
```

You can improve the naming by providing the `source` option which tells Rails which association to use on the model its joining through.

```
class Band < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :band_memberships
  has_many :members, through: :band_memberships, source: :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :band_memberships
  has_many :bands_as_member, through: :band_memberships, source: :band
end
```

Comment: Max, this is fantastic! I have to say that I'm still shaky on what's going on with the more intricate uses of ActiveRecord like the above, but I do understand much more than I did before, and I owe that to your excellent writing.

I followed along, and after making the relevant updates in seeds to test the relationships, I think it's functional. The Student><Band queries look perfect.  Oddly, I can use (e.g.) `Band.second.teacher` in the console and get the right user object, but `User.second.bands` and variants error or empty set. So how would I query to return a teacher's bands in console?

Comment: That's encouraging.  I did give that one a try.  The problem was I assumed it was off track due to the return appearing as: `=> #<Band::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x3fdc1077ed78>` instead of something like `=> #<Band id: 2, name: "Loic's Junior Marching Band", teacher_id: 2>`.  Is the return supposed to look like the former?

Comment: Correct, `has_many` associations return a CollectionProxy which is an array like object.

Comment: Aha!  I went back to see if I could then use any other finder methods to poke around in the proxy and discovered through the returns that I'd mistyped in the User model `foreign_key: 'Teacher_id'`.  Uncapitalizing the T made the return come out with all the info.

Cheers!